# Change a element of an array with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I initialized a new constant like that :

```
    const [data, setData] = useState([
     {
      id: "a1",
      score: "",
      name: "MyA1"
     },
     {
      id: "a2",
      score: "",
      name: "MyA2"
     }
    ]);
```

I want to change the score with setData. But I don't know how to access to data[0].score and data[1].score with setData

I tried to do :

```
    const updateList = (data) => {
      setData(previousState => {
        return { ...previousState, score:'Good' }
      });
    }
```

but it is not working because with this code I can't access to data[0]. I tried also :

```
   const updateList = (data) => {
      setData(previousState => {
        return { ...previousState, previousStat[0].score:'Good' }
      });
    }
```

but it is not working too.

Do you know how to do that ? Thank you !!

Comment: Are you meant to be changing _both_ object scores or just one identified by you somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by retrieve the current state of data using setState.
Try this.

```
const updateList = () => {
  setData(previousState => {
    const updatedData = previousState.map(item => {
      if (item.id === "a1") {
        return { ...item, score: "Good" };
      }
      return item;
    });
    return updatedData;
  });
};
```

If you have bigger data structure, then you can try using recursive approach:

```
const updateScoreRecursively = (data) => {
  return data.map(item => {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('score')) {
      return { ...item, score: "Good" };
    } else if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      return updateScoreRecursively(item);
    } else {
      return item;
    }
 });
};

const updateList = () => {
  setData(previousState => {
   return updateScoreRecursively(previousState);
 });
};
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It is very clear ! It is working but it is quite complicated for me because in reality, I have a bigger array with nested  arrays and lists inside and it is difficult to manage all the .map to access to my score value and to know exactly what to return. But thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that your useState hook is managing an array of objects. The first code snippet you provided is trying to spread the array like it's an object, which isn't quite right. The second snippet contains a syntax error (you're trying to use object property assignment inside the spread operator).
try this :

```
const updateList = () => {
setData(previousState => [
{ ...previousState[0], score: 'Good' },
  ...previousState.slice(1)
]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You could:

#### Shallow and deep Clones

- **create a copy** of the original array
- use the:

  - **find method** to get the first object that fits the condition
  - **filter method** to get all objects as a new array that fits the condition
- **update** the object
- **set the state** with the new/copied array

See examples:

`shallow clone`

```js
    const updateData = (id) => {
        // Make a copy of the current state
        let newData = [...data];

        // Update the newData array
        const dataToUpdate = newData.find(data => data.id === id);
        if(dataToUpdate) dataToUpdate.score = "Good";

        // Set new state with updated array
        setData(newData)
    }
```

`deep clone`

```js
  const updateData = (id) => {
    let newData = structuredClone(data);

    const dataToUpdate = newData.find((data) => data.id === id);
    if(dataToUpdate) dataToUpdate.score = "Good";

    setData(newData);
  };
```

Comment: Be very careful with this approach. Spreading the array of objects into a new array only copies the object references. If you change the score of an object in `newData` you'll be [updating the score in the original data too](https://jsfiddle.net/o2wmyc4j/). You should also check that `dataToDelete` actually returns something (the id might not match anything). If it doesn't your `dataToUpdate.score = "good"` will give an error.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It is working and I am careful because it's copying the reference. But maybe for a future issue, do you know how to make a real copy and not to just copy the object reference ? Your answer was very helpful because I have in reality a bigger array with nested lists and arrays inside. This method  saved me from making a lot of .map to access to the score.

Comment: I have added a second example where you can make a deep copy/clone of the array. This should normally give you the same structure and result as my first example. I also added Andy's about not having a condition checking for "no id".

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear from your question how you're meant to be updating the data - whether you want to update all the objects in one batch or whether you want to update *one* object's score based on its position in the array, but most likely you'll want to update an object based on its id.

This is an example on how you can update the dataset based on an object's id. To generate the HTML it `maps` over the data to produce a list of items. Each item has a data attribute which is the object id. Each item shows the name, and the score (or 'No score' if the object's score value is an empty string), and a button that amends the corresponding object's score to "Good" when clicked.

The `handleClick` handler uses `find` rather than `map` to update the state as `find` will short-circuit as soon as it finds a match whereas `map` is required to iterate over the whole array.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// For the sake of the example the data is passed into
// the component and the data state is set with it
function Example({ config }) {

  const [data, setData] = useState(config);
  
  // When a button is clicked it takes the id from the
  // dataset of the closest list item element. It clones the
  // current state. It then finds the index of the object where
  // its id matches the id from the item, sets the object's score
  // score value at using the index, and then updates the state
  // with the copied array. The state changes are reflected in the
  // re-rendered component.
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.closest('li').dataset;
    const copy = structuredClone(data);
    const found = copy.find(obj => obj.id === id);
    if (found) found.score = 'Good';
    setData(copy);
  }
  
  // Build a list of items using the data
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(obj => {
        
        const { id, name, score } = obj;
        
        return (
          <li key={id} data-id={id}>
            {name} {score.length ? score : 'No score'}
            <button onClick={handleClick}>
              Update score
            </button>
          </li>
        );
      
      })}
    </ul>
  );

}

const config=[{id:"a1",score:"",name:"MyA1"},{id:"a2",score:"",name:"MyA2"}];
const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example config={config} />);
```

```css
button { margin-left: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone)

Answer (score 0):

To update any item inside an state array:

```
function updateList(newItem){
  setData(current => current.map(currentItem => {
    if (currentItem.id === newItem.id) {
      return {...currentItem, ...newItem}
    }
    return currentItem
  }))
}
```

Now you can change/update your data calling this function:

```
updateList({
  id: "a1",
  score: "good",
  // you can omit this prop if you want
  name: "MyA1"
})
updateList({
  id: "a2",
  score: "bad"
})


// or
const newProps = [{
  id: "a1",
  score: "good",
  name: "MyA1"
},{
  id: "a2",
  score: "bad"
}]

newProps.map(newProp => updateList(newProp))
```

There are many ways to achieve the same result, this is only one approach. Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Your example contains a typo...

```
return { ...previousState, previousStat[0].score:'Good' }
```

Change previousStat to previousState

```
return { ...previousState, previousState[0].score:'Good' }
```

To the question, you can access the first array item, and also return a new state value like so...

```
const updateList = (data) => {
  setData(previousState => {
    const [ a1, a2 ] = previousState;
    a1.score = 'Good';
    a2.score = 'Excellent';
    return [ a1, a2 ]
  });
}
```